# How to prevent data loss while sending data to server?

Tags: android, networking, android-volley, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android app which is used to give feedback for a list of questions. After all the questions are answered I click the "submit" button to send data to server. To avoid data loss due to connectivity I have implemented a broadcast receiver. In the below the app starts sending the code when the connection is available otherwise stores it in local database. But what if the connection goes off while submitting

This is my implementation for `onClick()` method for submit button

```
    if (isConnectionAvailable(this)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < answereFinalList.size(); i++){
            count = i;
            Answere answere = answereFinalList . get (i);
            saveData(answere, answereFinalList);
            if (i == answereFinalList.size() - 1) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    } else {
        DbManager.getInstance(this).addAnsweres(answereFinalList);
        mainRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        submitRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say you're sending the data back you're sending it through an API?  If thats the case, you will get a success or a failure response back from the server letting you know if you data has been received or not.  My recommendation would be to have a sync flag on your data.

Start a service in your app when it makes sense, probably on login, submit button click, and maybe on internet connection changes depending on how frequently you want to send the data.  Have that service query the database for data with false set for synced, call the API, if you receive a 200 update that data so true for synced, or delete it from your local.  If you get back any errors IE server is down, connection dropped, etc... don't update the flag, and have the service try again after x amount of time.  Or when internet connection is restored, etc...

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services